# Running an app on the simulator for the first time causing unknown data spike

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

Every time I close the simulator and run it again or when it launches on restart of my mac the simulator downloads approximately 300MB of some data. Initially, I didn't know what was causing this data spike on my computer. When I checked the network monitor I noticed that there was a process called `nsurlsessiond` which was the reason for this data spike.

[image: activity monitor]

Upon further observation, I found out that every time I launch the simulator for running an app the data spike happens. I'm positive the data spike is not caused by the app, launching the simulator without Xcode also causes the same. If the simulator is already launched and you're just running the app again wouldn't cause this. If the simulator launch is immediate again it doesn't happen.

1. What exactly is the reason for this network spike?
2. What exactly is the simulator downloading?
3. How can I stop this from happening? Will stopping this cause any issues?

Comment: What version of XCode? Do you have a physical device connected with an Apple Watch? Do you have an Apple Watch connected to simulator?

Comment: @xTwisteDx I think Xcode version doesn't matter. I got the same in 11.4 and 12.0. No physical device, no watch connected to simulator.

Comment: The only other thought I have is maybe your symbols are being downloaded. Open your device panel at launch and check to see if it's fetching symbols.